# Sorted table with parameter t_table of cl_salv_table class

Tags: abap

If I use the internal table as a standard table the parameter T_TABLE accepts normally,
but when I declare as a sorted table this error happen: "ITUSER" is not type-compatible with formal parameter "T_TABLE".

Can you guys help me identify why this happens?

```
TABLES: USER_ADDR,USR41.

TYPES: BEGIN OF LINE02_TYPE,
         Z_BNAME TYPE USER_ADDR-BNAME,
         Z_NAME  TYPE USER_ADDR-NAME_FIRST,
         Z_LAST  TYPE USER_ADDR-NAME_LAST,
         Z_TERMI TYPE USR41-TERMINAL,
         Z_LASTD TYPE USR41-LOGON_DATE,
         Z_KOSTL TYPE USER_ADDR-KOSTL,
       END OF LINE02_TYPE.

DATA: ITUSER  TYPE SORTED TABLE OF LINE02_TYPE WITH UNIQUE KEY Z_BNAME,
      "ITUSER TYPE standard TABLE OF line02_type,
      R_TABLE TYPE REF TO CL_SALV_TABLE.

START-OF-SELECTION.

  SELECT A~BNAME A~NAME_FIRST A~NAME_LAST B~TERMINAL B~LOGON_DATE A~KOSTL  FROM USER_ADDR AS A
    LEFT JOIN USR41 AS B ON B~BNAME = A~BNAME
     INTO TABLE ITUSER.

  CALL METHOD CL_SALV_TABLE=>FACTORY
    IMPORTING
      R_SALV_TABLE = R_TABLE
    CHANGING
      T_TABLE      = ITUSER.

  CALL METHOD R_TABLE->DISPLAY.
```

Comment: `why this happens` this happens because it is inherent limitation of CL_SALV_TABLE, it requires only standard table, you cannot bypass this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I do not see it is documented anywhere but `T_TABLE` has to be a `STANDARD TABLE`. If you dig deeper into `FACTORY` method the `T_TABLE` parameter is passed to `SET_DATA` method which requires the table as `STANDARD TABLE`

```
  try.
      r_salv_table->set_data(
        changing
          t_table = t_table ).
    catch cx_salv_no_new_data_allowed.                  "#EC NO_HANDLER
  endtry.
```

Moreover if you define the parameter as `TABLE` a `STANDARD TABLE` is implicitely meant. Here is the [reference](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/de-DE/abentyping_generic.htm)

Comment: Do you know an alternative for me to display a sorted table in a ALV? Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, the signature for `factory` is `changing t_table type table`.
`TABLE` is a generic ABAP type which is the old way to say `STANDARD TABLE`.

This is required since actions you perform via the `ALV` are reflected on the table itself. When you press the sort button the internal table will also be sorted (hence also `changing`). So when you get e.g. the double click event, you can safely access `my_table[ row ]` since it's sorted in the same way as it's displayed to the user.
Such a sorting cannot be represented in `HASHED TABLE` or `SORTED TABLE` (sort can be on any column/s).